# Change color for a selected string in qtable in Pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm new to PyQt programming and I'm designing a GUI using qt4 designer. In the GUI i have a table which gets populated once when i hit a button. The GUI appears like the one in the following picture:

[image]

Now in the table i want the strings in the "status" column to be coloured i.e "checked" string to "green" and "not_checked" string to "red"

How can i do this, can i do this using style sheets? Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use `QtGui.QItemDelegate` to delegate show your data. Your also available in `QTableWidget` and `QTableView`. Implement in `QItemDelegate.paint (self, QPainter painter, QStyleOptionViewItem option, QModelIndex index)` method.

In that method, If column in your custom field (In this case column 2), Paint with your custom color it in paint. And implement your custom `QtGui.QItemDelegate` completed, Put in your `QTableWidget` or `QTableView` by use `QAbstractItemView.setItemDelegate (self, QAbstractItemDelegate delegate)`.

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ENUM_STATUS:
    CHECKED     = QtCore.QString('checked')
    NOT_CHECKED = QtCore.QString('not_checked')

class QCustomDelegate (QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def paint (self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 1:
            textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
            if   textQString == ENUM_STATUS.CHECKED:
                currentQColor = QtCore.Qt.darkGreen
            elif textQString == ENUM_STATUS.NOT_CHECKED:
                currentQColor = QtCore.Qt.darkRed
            else:
                currentQColor = QtCore.Qt.darkGray
            painterQPainter.setPen(currentQColor)
            painterQPainter.drawText(optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter, textQString)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        ### <! This is initiate your QTableWidget or QTableView, Your code >! ###
        listsHorizontalHeaderItem = ['Name', 'Status']
        self.setColumnCount(len(listsHorizontalHeaderItem))
        for index in range(self.columnCount()):
            self.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(listsHorizontalHeaderItem[index]))
        listsData = [
            ['Mr. A', ENUM_STATUS.CHECKED],
            ['Mr. B', ENUM_STATUS.NOT_CHECKED],
            ['Mr. C', ENUM_STATUS.NOT_CHECKED],
            ['Mr. D', ENUM_STATUS.CHECKED],
            ['Mr. E', ENUM_STATUS.CHECKED]]
        self.setRowCount(len(listsData))
        for row in range(len(listsData)):
            for column in range(len(listsData[row])):
                self.setItem(row, column, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(listsData[row][column]))
        ### <! End initiate >! ###

        # After initiated, Your have to setup delegate to your QTableWidget or QTableView, Add line
        self.myQCustomDelegate = QCustomDelegate()
        self.setItemDelegate(self.myQCustomDelegate)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQCustomTableWidget = QCustomTableWidget()
    myQCustomTableWidget.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked....@Kitsune Meyoko and is there any simple way, may be by using style sheets?? do you know that?? I've tried but i'm not getting the output by changing the stylesheet

Comment: as I know, It's set all column & row, not have specified column. Your can read style-sheet reference : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html and this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html.